# Create XML with C# object

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have a C# object which I need to change into XML.

My C# object looks like this.

```
public class XmlModel
{      
    public string NodeName { get; set; }
    public int NodeId { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public string NodeValue { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a list of object like this.

```html
NodeName : "Parent" , NodeId : "1" , ParentId:"0" NodeValue=""
NodeName : "Child" , NodeId : "2" , ParentId:"1" NodeValue=""
NodeName : "Name" , NodeId : "4" , ParentId:"3" NodeValue="Person Name"
NodeName : "LastName" , NodeId : "5" , ParentId:"3" NodeValue="Last Name"
NodeName : "Contact" , NodeId : "3" , ParentId:"2" NodeValue="54565465"

NodeName : "Child" , NodeId : "6" , ParentId:"1" NodeValue=""
NodeName : "Address" , NodeId : "7" , ParentId:"6" NodeValue=""
NodeName : "Home" , NodeId : "8" , ParentId:"7" NodeValue="Home Address"
NodeName : "Office" , NodeId : "9" , ParentId:"7" NodeValue="Address"
```

Now I need to create an XML file using `XDocument` and `XElement`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use XmlSerializer for XML serialization. Below is a sample snippet.

```js
 XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
 var subReq = new MyObject();
 var xml = "";

 using(var sww = new StringWriter())
 {
     using(XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
     {
         xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, subReq);
         xml = sww.ToString(); // Your XML
     }
 }
```

Comment: What if I don't have an concrete class of which you have created an object to serialize the xml ??